# Sandboxes and Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal Sites?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, testing, joomla, sandbox

I'm looking into building database driven websites based on opensource platforms in a sandbox area rather than having them accessible via the final URL until clients have paid up.

Is anyone aware of any problems this may cause with paths or functionality, or, know of any good articles on the subject?

many thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a cut-down, less privileged or demo account for signup users that can still enjoy the overall experience of your site without the full functionality of your killer-webapp services. "Restricting" them in a Sandbox area that is not even the actual site would not be as appealing and convincing as it could be for them to go from "freemium to premium" customers.

Comment: Hi dimitrisli, thanks for the response but this isn't really what I need to achive. I want the client to be able to view the full version of the final site but want to have it hosted in a test area ie. www.websitename.com/sandbox until signed-off and paid for before moving the site to root www.websitename.com and allowing the client to make it available to the public.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you go the subdomain route. In the admin page of your site provider interface you would be able to first create the subdomain like: http://sandbox.websitename.com. The interface depends on your site host provider but for me it's the "Parallels Business Automation" and it's really easy to setup (I'm hosting a Joomla CMS for that matter). This subdomain has access to your mysql instances so you could use the same as in the main site or have a cut-down version of your site connected in a new db responding to the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no bad effect on functionality just because it is in sandbox. Generally, Joomla is almost location independent (untill and unless you are driving multiple websites from same joomla installation)
2. For security purpose secure the URL via .htaccess file (if more security required then  setup a cron to update password every X hours, and email new details to user)

Answer (score 0):

I develop all joomla sites on a local server and then upload to the production server once approved. In Joomla, when I upload the files to the production server, I usually need to change the mysql server as well and it can all be changed from the configuration.php file

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for but I'd rather not be hosting them on a local machine. If it's just a matter of editing database paths then I'll do some testing, I'assuming the $log_path and $tmp_path need updating but was unsure if Joomla also uses a base url.